# Rendering an .Rmd fails because stringr.rdb is corrupt?

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-package

When I render a vignette with

```
rmarkdown::render('/path/to/pkg/vignettes/my-vignette.Rmd')
```

I encounter the error

```
processing file: draft-vignette.Rmd
Error in get0(oNam, envir = ns) : 
  lazy-load database '/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringr/R/stringr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Running `devtools::build_vignettes(pkg = '/path/to/pkg')` produces a similar error.

Strangely,

```
devtools::build(pkg = '/path/to/pkg')
```

runs successfully, produces the compressed package file and it also renders the vignette correctly.

I have also tried removing/reinstalling the `stringr` package but this did not help.

I want to render only the vignette and nothing else, so how to fix the above error?

Comment: I met this problem before. Maybe I just restart R session, remove and reinstall `stringr`. Or maybe I remove and installed the newer github version of `stringr`. It do need to install `stringi` from source which took quite some time.

Comment: !!! Restarted the R session and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Technically the error comes from zlib's uncompress error Z_DATA_ERROR (the compressed data was corrupted).

Answer (score 7):

Per the comment from dracodoc, just restart the R session.